# pandas column result based on result of below cell (row) in separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think this should be relatively easy but I'm a noob!

Need to return results in a new pandas column (call this column B) that is based on the result of the below row in column A.

Please print the below code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['BUY', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'HODL', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'SELL','BUY']})
print(df)
```

I need a new column (column B) to return results based on following.

Starting from the bottom of the pandas dataframe. The last cell in column A (ie A18 = 'BUY') can always return the same result for last cell in column B.

The next row up in column A (ie A17) is a 'SELL'.  I regard this as a change and as such cell B17 should now also be a 'SELL'

The next row up in column A (ie A16) is a 'SELL' again.  As this is no change from A17, cell B16 should now be a 'NA'

The next row up in column A (ie A15) is a 'HODL'.  All 'HODL' cells should always be reflected as 'HODL' cells in column B

If cell A15 was however a 'SELL' again another 'NA' would be applied in column B.

The same princples for 'SELL' cells apply for 'BUY' cells

The following df has been provided only to provide a visualisation of the expected result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['BUY', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'HODL', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'SELL','BUY'], 'B': ['NA', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'HODL', 'BUY', 'NA', 'SELL', 'NA', 'BUY', 'HODL', 'NA', 'NA', 'SELL', 'HODL', 'NA', 'SELL','BUY']})

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `numpy.select & Series.shift`

We can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this so we can define multiple conditions and based on those conditions we can assign values to your new column B.

In our conditions we use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) which we use so we can check if the next value is `SELL` or `BUY`.

[`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) is the same as using `== 'SELL'` for example

**Note** I reverse your dataframe, since you want to apply the logic from the bottom up, I do this with `df[::-1]`. Which is the same method to reverse a list in Python.

```
# Reverse dataframe
df = df[::-1]

conditions = [
    df['A'].eq('HODL'),
    df['A'].eq('SELL') & df['A'].shift().eq('SELL'),
    df['A'].eq('BUY') & df['A'].shift().eq('BUY')
]

choices = ['HODL', 'NA', 'NA']

df['B'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df['A'])

# Reverse dataframe back to original state
df = df[::-1]
```

### **Output**

```
print(df)
       A     B
0    BUY    NA
1    BUY   BUY
2   HODL  HODL
3   SELL  SELL
4   HODL  HODL
5   HODL  HODL
6    BUY   BUY
7   SELL    NA
8   SELL  SELL
9    BUY    NA
10   BUY   BUY
11  HODL  HODL
12  SELL    NA
13  SELL    NA
14  SELL  SELL
15  HODL  HODL
16  SELL    NA
17  SELL  SELL
18   BUY   BUY
```